# Vector 3 array ,how to assign positions to Vector3 array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We're trying to put positions in Vector3 array by taking their position in another vector and putting it in as an index in the Vector3 array. We're trying to make a board game,and we want to move the player to one of the positions of the Vector3 array.

```
public static Vector3[] Steps;

public static void Position()
{
    Vector3 step = GameObject.Find("Step").transform.position;

    Steps[0] = step;

    Vector3 step1 = GameObject.Find("Step (1)").transform.position;
    Steps[1] = step1;
```

and so on

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do i input the Vector3 position to the array,attm like this it doesnt input the x,y,z positions in the array.and i cant call the index of the array to move it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before assigning values to the array you will have to initialize it with a size like e.g.

```
public static Vector3[] Steps;

public static void Position()
{
    Steps = new Vector3[someSize];

    Vector3 step = GameObject.Find("Step").transform.position;

    Steps[0] = step;

    Vector3 step1 = GameObject.Find("Step (1)").transform.position;
    Steps[1] = step1;
}
```

that `someSize` ofcourse has to match the amount of positions you are going to add.

Or instead rather do it dynamically using a list like

```
public static List<Vector3> Steps = new List<Vector3>();

public static void Position()
{
    // optionally remove current values first
    Steps.Clear();

    Steps = new Vector3[someSize];

    Vector3 step = GameObject.Find("Step").transform.position;

    Steps.Add(step);

    Vector3 step1 = GameObject.Find("Step (1)").transform.position;
    Steps.Add(step1);
}
```

you access later exactly the same way

```
Steps[index]
```

---

Easier would be if you already can reference your GameObjects in the Scene beforehand you should do rather something like

```
[SerializeField] private List<Transform> _steps = new List<Transform>();
```

and simply reference all your GameObjects in this list via the inspector in Unity. This way you don't even need to get the positions directly but could simply publish this list like

```
[SerializeField] private List<Transform> _steps = new List<Transform>();

public static List<Transform> Steps;

private void Awake()
{
    Steps = _steps;
}
```

and access them like

```
Steps[index].position
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multi array:

```
List<List<Vector3>> Positions;
```

Then you will have a "2D board" and the positions look like so:

```
Positions[1][4];
```

Plus, your question is a bit confusing and hard to understand what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so guessing by your stated question I am guessing you are somewhat new to Unity right? So I will go over this a bit more detailed.

First thing I would fix is to make an instance of your class and not a static one. (Instanced one is the script that you can drog onto a game object) This is done so you can reference all objects much easily and actually make interacting of objects work. (If you wish to learn more about the use for this i can recommend you this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgvq8MUtfTo)

Next mistake would be that you did not initialize zhe array. Arrays in object oriented are a bit more tricky then in other languages like let's say Python for example. Here you need to explicitly either set the contents of the array when you initialize it, or at least define its length. This is something that you CANNOT change later on. If you wish to take a more dynamic approach at storing variables for C# I would take a look at Lists. (Check this out if you are unsure as to what exactly is different: https://www.educba.com/c-sharp-array-vs-list/)

And the final thing that is really bad if you get used to doing it is getting references to game object using the find method. While it works for sure and I'm guessing its fast for your example, once you fill your scene with game object it WILL grind to a halt. Its better to just drag refs to the object at the start OR if you are instantiating objects at runtime, you can keep track then.

So overall ASSUMING you have all the objects in the scene, I would solve your issue this way:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] figures;

    void Start(){
        foreach(GameObject figure in figures){
            //this is where you get all of their positions
            Debug.log(figure.transform.position)
        }
    }

}
```

Bear in mind that you will have to assign the figure before the start to the component variable. You can read more about this here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VariablesAndTheInspector.html

Hope this helpsyou with your game!